# How to recognize angular-cli version which is used in Angular2+ project

Tags: angular

I have old angular 2+ project and wanted to know what is `angular-cli` version need to be install to run the project.

Comment: You can check required CLI version from `package.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

Inside package.json, in `devDependencies`, there's `@angular/cli` entry.

Answer (score 0):

Run "ng --version"  , It will give you detailed response with the version of all the core package along with CLI.